# VRML file loading issue in three.js

Tags: three.js, vrml

I am trying to load vrml or wrl file using vrmlloader.js which is available in three.js library. After loading this file its showing nothing its showing only white blank page.

Content of VRML file is available here : http://jsfiddle.net/shiladittya/y0j1wn0c/

And I am read this vrml file by using below code :

```
            var loader = new THREE.VRMLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
                var geometry = event.content;
                scene.add(geometry);
            } );
            loader.load( "./stl/test.WRL" );
```

What I missed? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include Detector.js (available in three.js library) and jQuery (2.0 or newer version).

But, for now this is the older version of code.
Now, in the latest version of VrmlLoader.js, you have to write:

```
var loader = new THREE.VRMLLoader();
loader.load("./stl/test.WRL", function(object) {
    scene.add(object);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried loading you example in the new VrmlParser project. It loads just fine. Could you try it there?

I must note that I had to reduce the indentation, the file should not start with a tab character (\t).

You can find the VrmlParser project here: https://github.com/bartmcleod/VrmlParser

It uses ThreeJs.